# Can we have access to Greek kai?

Tags: symbols, letters

I would very much like to have access to the following Greek ancestor of the modern ampersand:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kai_(conjunction)#Ligature

Can you help me?

Comment: Doesn't one of the unicode fonts have it?

Comment: @cfr It seems that I cannot implement Unicode on my version of Texstudio.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. TeXStudio is just an editor - it has nothing to do with whether you can use unicode or not. (Unless it cannot deal with unicode-encoded files, which is extremely unlikely, to say the least.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peter Baker’s [Junicode](https://sourceforge.net/projects/junicode/files/junicode/), in its latest versions, includes Foulis Greek, where the character appears at U+03D7. (The glyph is also present in the very old version of Junicode supplied with TeX Live, as part of `Junicode.ttf`, but you’ll want the newest version, which you can install in your personal collection of fonts and use  with xetex or luatex.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[greek.ancient,english]{babel}
\setmainfont{Junicode}[
  Contextuals=Alternate]
\newfontface\foulis{Foulis Greek}[
  Script=Greek]
\begin{document}
This is {\foulis ϗ}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The commercial typeface [Lascaris](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/lascaris/lascaris/) also has this and many other ligatures.

You comment that you’re having trouble with unicode. FontForge makes it possible to save a glyph as an `.svg` image, which you can then convert to `.pdf` and use as any other graphic. Other questions on this site explain the procedure (see, for example, [convert LaTeX symbols into svg files using font files directly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298063)).

Comment: There are *many* fonts that provide the character: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAh4a.jpg)

Comment: Thanks @egreg. That looks like a very useful Mac application. For those who don’t have a Mac, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03d7/fontsupport.htm is useful (unfortunately, it requires Adobe Flash to show local fonts).

Comment: I get error comments when loading \usepackage{fontspec}.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal What exactly does the error message say?  Are you trying to use `fontspec` with pdftex instead of xetex or luatex?  That’s bound to fail.

Comment: @Thérèse When trying 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}

I get 


  The~ fontspec~ package~ requires~ either~ XeTeX~ or~ LuaTeX.\\\\
  You~ must~ change~ your~ typesetting~ engine~ to,~ e.g.,~ "xelatex"~ or~ "lualatex" instead~ of~ plain~ "latex"~ or~ "pdflatex".
 }
\msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}

Comment: So how do I change to XeTeX or LuaTex?

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal I don’t have TeXstudio installed, but unless you haven’t updated it since before the Flood, it should allow you to save your file in utf-8 encoding (that’s essential; http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION01) and to choose xelatex or lualatex as your compiler (http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a).

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal `…texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/lualatex/lualatex-doc/lualatex-doc.pdf` needs updating but is still useful as a brief introduction to lualatex.

Comment: So I have UTF-8 encoding as default.

Comment: I was now able to switch to LuLaTeX and to xelatex.

Comment: @Thérèse Thanks. It seems that documents I have already written will not compile well with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. I will need to study some more on these matters to see how I may profit from their advantages.

Comment: @Thérèse Yyour link to an introduction on lualatex is not working, unfortunately.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal I can’t know what your directory structure looks like; that’s the last part of the path in a standard installation of TeX Live 2018.  You can search for the filename on ctan.org if you can’t find a local copy.